# Incorporate the highlight_file results into textarea

Tags: php

i try to wrote highlight file to text area,

```
<?php
    $hasil = highlight_file("test.php", true); 
    echo '<textarea type="text" name="code" rows="40" cols="120">'; 
    echo $hasil; 
    echo '</textarea>'; 
?>
```

how to remove the generated style in textarea?

Comment: If you want edit your code then you can use bellow code or you want code formated with color then you can use any editor for showing your code .

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing the generated style just open the file normally and put it in the textarea

```
  <?php $hasil = file_get_contents("test.php"); 
  echo '<textarea type="text" name="code" rows="40" cols="120">'; 
  echo $hasil; 
  echo '</textarea>'; ?>
```

alternatively you can use `strip_tags` to remove all the styles from the highlighted output